# EntityFieldQuery get total of paged results

Tags: paging, database

I have added a pager to my query with `$query->pager(6);` but I also want to display a total number of results. For example, if there are 8 results I want to display `Search results (8)` with 6 per page but I don't know how to get the total number of results, the query only ever returns an array of up to 6 elements so I can't add them all up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its quite a while since this answer, but global $pager_total_items as given in another answer gives the totals of all the different pagers on the page.

After executing your query that has a pager, you access the total in $query->pager['total'].

Answer (score 0):

As usual, I find an answer soon after asking :P

If anyone's wondering, there is a global $pager_total_items https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/pager_total_items/7